# Removing for loops to enable parallel computing with numpy arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy, for-loop, parallel-processing, numpy-ndarray

Is there any way(like vectorization of numpy arrays for parallel processing) to remove the two for loops and parallelize this code?

```
state_returns = np.zeros((10,10,dtype = np.ndarray))
value_function = np.zeros((10,10))
........................#further code to fill the values in array:state_returns
........................#Eg. state_returns = [[[1,2,3,..],[2,3,6,...],...],[[3,9,7,...],[5,8,6...],....],......]
........................#Eg. value_function = [[2,4,6,....],[6,5,7,...],....]
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        n = state_returns[i,j].shape[0]-1
        value_function[i,j] = state_returns[i,j].sum()/n if (n!=0) else 0
```

Comment: Little confused. `state_returns[i,j]` is always a scalar so taking the `.sum()` doesn't make any sense. If you better explain what you're trying to do (realistic input, expected output), I'm sure we can get rid of the loops using basic broadcasting

Comment: @PaulH Its given that elements of state_returns have dtype = np.ndarray, hence all elements are numpy arrays. Also all these array elements contained in the 10*10 numpy array can have different sizes(n,).

Comment: If you make your array not ragged, you won't need a loop at all

Comment: Please provide a proper working example.  Your sample arrays are incomplete.  Your use of `np.zeros` is wrong.  Before trying 'parallel processing', try to write effective numpy code.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, your calculations are element-wise. That is, the value of `value_function[i,j]` has no influence on `value_function[n,m]` for `i != n` and `j != m`. This means that you can easily run your code in parallel. Here an example using the threading library and 10 threads (I didn't actually check if the code works but hopefully you get the idea):

```
import threading      

def calculation(i):
    global state_returns, value_function
    for j in range(10):
        n = state_returns[i,j].shape[0]-1
        value_function[i,j] = state_returns[i,j].sum()/n if (n!=0) else 0

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    t = []
    for i in range(0, 10):
        t.append(threading.Thread(target=calculation, args=(i,)))
    for i in range(0, 10):
        t[i].start()
    for i in range(0, 10):
        t[i].join()
```

You may need to lock the variables within the def if you're running into problems.